# Lists & Keys in ReactJS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, react-component

Im converting some HTML to ReactJS and I am trying to use the transform list functionality. 
What I mean: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

I would really appreciate some help.

The Error I am getting is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
The compiler is pointing to this line as the issue:

```
const menuPizzaList = props.pizzaItems.map((item) =>
```

Here is all the code in the file:

```
    import React from 'react';

    function PizzaList(props) {

        const menuPizzaList = props.pizzaItems.map((item) =>

            <div key={item.id}>
                <br />
                <h1><b>{item.title}</b><span className="w3-tag w3-red w3-round">{item.special}</span>
                    <span className="w3-right w3-tag w3-dark-grey w3-round">{item.price}</span></h1>
                <p className="w3-text-grey">{item.about}</p>
            </div>
        );

        return (
            <div>
                {menuPizzaList}
            </div>
        )

    }

    export default PizzaList;
```

The data is getting retrieved from an array:

```
    //JSON object with menu items for pizza 
    const pizzaItems = [
        {id:1, title:'Margherita', price:'$12.50', about: 'Fresh tomatoes, fresh mozzarella, fresh basil'},
        {id:2, title:'Formaggio', price:'$15.50', about: 'Four cheeses (mozzarella, parmesan, pecorino, jarlsberg)'},
        {id:3, title:'Chicken', price:'$17.00', about: 'Fresh tomatoes, mozzarella, chicken, onions'},
        {id:4, title:'Pineapple"o"clock', price:'$16.50', about: 'Fresh tomatoes, mozzarella, fresh pineapple, bacon, fresh basil'},
        {id:5, title:'Meat Town', special: 'Hot!', price:'$20.00', about: 'Fresh tomatoes, mozzarella, hot pepporoni, hot sausage, beef, chicken'},
        {id:6, title:'Parma', special: 'NEW', price:'$21.00', about: 'Fresh tomatoes, mozzarella, parma, bacon, fresh arugula'}

    ];
```

And the data after gets passed into this

```
    <PizzaList items={pizzaItems}></PizzaList>
```

Comment: You are passing the data as `items` and not pizzaItems either change `<PizzaList pizzaItems={pizzaItems}></PizzaList>` or change `this.props.items.map(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change 
`<PizzaList items={pizzaItems}></PizzaList>`
To
`<PizzaList pizzaItems={pizzaItems}></PizzaList>`